# sudo: account validation failure, is your account locked? Centos 7 a la hora de instalar programas

Tags: linux, centos7

Estoy utilizando un vps(Centos 7) por medio de una consola ssh y a la hora de instalar postgresql desde su documentación oficial me genera este error: sudo: account validation failure, is your account locked?
¿Esto a que se debe?

Comment: Probaste a entrar en modo `su`?

Comment: @winset Efectivamente lo probé pero sigue presentando el mismo problema